# which are the good camcorder or DSLR to make video tutorials or MOOC to show on wide screen using projector?

Tags: camera

I need your help to find best video recording equipment for shooting videos for online video dissemination and projector based.

Please help me to know that what is the difference between shooting videos using

Sony HXR NX1 Video Camera

Panasonic HC-W850K Digital HD Camcorder (Black)

Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam (Black)

Nikon D5200 24.1MP Digital SLR Camera (Black)

Kodak PlayTouch Video Camera

How can i find recorded videos using each of this camera to compare output of each of camera and to know about limitation.

Can we shoot following videos using above camera?

10 Common Expressions in English

Matriz inversa, traspuesta y adjunta BACHILLERATO matematicas

Introduction to Limits (mathbff)

CA Ankita Mehta Patni - IPCC law lecture

Interview Question: Tell Me Something About Yourself?

Lecture1 - Introduction to Digital Circuits

Lecture - 1 Introduction to Data Structures and Algorithms

What is SharePoint? | lynda.com overview

HarvardX: CS50x3 Introduction to Computer Science

Lec 1 | MIT 6.00 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming, Fall 2008

Calligraphy_Devanagari_Letters

Thanks

Comment: How are you planning to record sound?

Answer (score 2):

The SONY HXR NX1 is a staple of capturing professional-grade content that can be produced on its own or incorporated into other productions.  Yes, there are higher-end cameras, but this is a solid choice for a pro-level classroom.  I have seen this camera in many classrooms.  With a good operator, and a decent sound-recording system, you will be in the top quintile of production.

The Panasonic HC-850K has a marketing gimmick of being able to produce two video views at once, such as a wide view and a zoomed-in view.  I have not used this camera, but its relatively low price and very modern technology make it a sensible choice for somebody looking to prototype a solution, learn the limits of the camera, and then buy what's really needed without losing too much investment.

The Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam is suitable if the scope of your subject is basically just sitting in front of it.  If your talking head talks while seated in front of a computer, great.  But if your talking head talks and walks (such as in front of a lecture board), it won't suit.  Similarly, if your demonstration requires aiming the camera at anything more interesting than a talking head, you will likely find the ergonomics of the webcam to be not worth the hassle.

A Nikon D5200 24.1MP Digital SLR Camera (and any other SLR) is probably a terrible choice for your application.  These cameras really are optimized for still shooting.  Yes, they do shoot video.  Yes, the video sounds like it has a good spec.  But the reality is they come with all sorts of limitations (such as a maximum 29 minute recording time).  And you need to get much more expensive and much less capable lenses to fill a sensor size you don't need/can't use for video.  DSLR video is always at least one step below a similarly priced true video camera.  And the lenses cost extra, compared with many video cameras, which have them built-in.

The Kodak PlayTouch Video Camera (and similar) are popular for "flipped" classrooms.  I.e., classrooms where both teachers and students can contribute video content to the overall experience.  If your MOOC idea involves student-contributed content, then giving everybody a level playing field can be a good idea.  But if you want to "produce" something, the limitations of these cameras will drive your producer crazy.

Comment: I have one more sub question in this. 

I have listed few videos samples. can we shoot those using these cameras.